# How do I sum a sub-list in linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I would like sum a property on a sub list of a list ... example:

I have:

```
public class List1 {
public List<List2> List2 { get; set; }
}

public class List2 {
public int TotalUnits { get; set; }
}
```

In my view I have a `List<List1>`, so that I want to do something like:

```
<%= Model.List1.Where(x.List2.Any()).Sum(x=>x.TotalUnits) .%>
```

Obviously everything after Sum doesn't work, but is there a way I can do this in a single line without having to create a new Dto on my server side?

Comment: Your first `.Where` is missing an argument or something.  There is no `x`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Are you trying to get the sum of all of the `TotalUnits` in every `List2` instance?  If so then do the following

```
<%= Model.List1.SelectMany(x => x.List2).Sum(x => x.TotalUnits) %>
```

Here's how this works

```
Model.List1.SelectMany(x => x.List2)
```

This takes the `List<List1>` and transforms it into an `IEnumerable<List2>`.  `SelectMany` is similar to `Select` in that it's a projection for elements in an enumeration except that it expects an enumerable result.  The collection of enumerable results is then put into a single enumerable.  Or in simpler words, it flattens a list of lists.

```
.Sum(x => x.TotalUnits)
```

This just sums the `TotalUnits` member of `List2`.

There is also a small typo in your code.  I believe it should read as follows (note the missing `class` keyword)

```
public int TotalUnits { get; set;}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for something like this:

```
Model.List1.Where(x => x.List2.Any()).Select(x => x.List2.Sum(y => y.TotalUnits))
```

This will give you a list of sums of the sublists that contain elements.