# Sum of int's in a nested list

Tags: c#, list, sum

trying to figure this out...

I have a list like this:

```
public List<myScore> mScore = new List<myScore>();
```

myScore looks like this:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class myScore
{
    public string playerId;
    public List<scores> scores;
}
```

scores look like this:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class myScore
{
    public int kills;
    public int points;
}
```

Now, what I am trying to accomplish here is to get the sum of all points into a variable for use later on. Sp lets say that i want the score for the first player in the mScore list, I am trying to go this way:

```
int tPoints = mScore[0].scores.points.Sum(NOT SURE WHAT TO DO HERE);
```

Really hope someone can help me on this and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum nested values with Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893445/sum-nested-values-with-linq) It seems to be an exact duplicate, which can be found in a few seconds, as well as [How do I sum a sub-list in linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138866/how-do-i-sum-a-sub-list-in-linq)

Comment: Actualy you need `scores.Sum(x => x.points)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Enumerable.Sum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Sum__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Nullable_System_Int32___) has overloads accepting selector so you can define what to sum. It should be applied to enumeration (`IEnumerable`) in your case it is `List<scores> scores`:

```
int tPoints = mScore[0].scores.Sum(s => s.points);
```